# zlib different decompresssion size

Tags: c++, zlib

I am trying to use zlib for decompression. Im look at a tutorial at zlib site and inflate codes produce different size output.

```
int CZLib::Inflate() {
    int ret;
    unsigned int have;
    z_stream zstream;
    unsigned char in[CHUNK];
    unsigned char out[CHUNK];

    zstream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    zstream.zfree = Z_NULL;
    zstream.opaque = Z_NULL;
    zstream.avail_in = 0;
    zstream.next_in = Z_NULL;
    ret = inflateInit(&zstream);
    if (ret != Z_OK)
        return ret;

    do {
        zstream.avail_in = fread(in, 1, CHUNK, fin);
        if (ferror(fin)) {
            (void)inflateEnd(&zstream);
            return Z_ERRNO;
        }
        if (zstream.avail_in == 0) break;
        zstream.next_in = in;

        do {
            zstream.avail_out = CHUNK;
            zstream.next_out = out;
            ret = inflate(&zstream, Z_NO_FLUSH);
            assert(ret != Z_STREAM_ERROR);
            switch (ret) {
                case Z_NEED_DICT:
                    ret = Z_DATA_ERROR;
                case Z_DATA_ERROR:
                case Z_MEM_ERROR:
                    (void)inflateEnd(&zstream);
                    return ret;
            }
            have = CHUNK - zstream.avail_out;
            if (fwrite(out, 1, have, fout) != have || ferror(fout)) {
                (void)inflateEnd(&zstream);
                return Z_ERRNO;
            }

        } while (zstream.avail_out == 0);
    } while (ret != Z_STREAM_END);

    (void)inflateEnd(&zstream);
    return ret == Z_STREAM_END ? Z_OK : Z_DATA_ERROR;
}
```

and other

```
int CZLib::Inflate(const std::string& src) {
    std::vector<char> output;

    z_stream zstream;
    zstream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    zstream.zfree = Z_NULL;
    zstream.opaque = Z_NULL;
    zstream.avail_in = 0;
    zstream.next_in = Z_NULL;

    int ret = inflateInit(&zstream);
    if (ret != Z_OK)
        return ret;

    unsigned char in[CHUNK];
    unsigned char out[CHUNK];

    int have = 0, nByte = CHUNK, off = 0, remaining = src.size();

    if (src.size() < CHUNK) nByte = src.size();
    do {
        memcpy(in, &src[off], nByte);
        off += nByte;
        remaining -= nByte;

        if (nByte > 0) zstream.avail_in = nByte;

        if (remaining > CHUNK) { nByte = CHUNK; }
        else { nByte = remaining; }

        if (zstream.avail_in == 0) break;
        zstream.next_in = in;

        do {
            zstream.avail_out = CHUNK;
            zstream.next_out = out;

            ret = inflate(&zstream, Z_NO_FLUSH);
            have = CHUNK - zstream.avail_out;
            output.insert(output.end(), out, out + have);

        } while (zstream.avail_out == 0);
    } while (ret != Z_STREAM_END);

    CFile* file = new CFile("in.out", "wb");
    file->Write<char>(&output[0], output.size());
    delete file;
    return ret;
}
```

Its uses same data. One of them reads file on disk and other uses memory (buffer method). CHUNK size 16384. First code produce 524288(0x80000) and other 524800 (0x80200) byte. The difference are 512 bytes. Why is it happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first code example you have this line

```
zstream.avail_in = fread(in, 1, CHUNK, fin);
```

and then you have

```
if (zstream.avail_in == 0) break;
```

to stop the loop.

In the second code example, you have the same line to stop the loop but you also have this line:

```
    if (nByte > 0) zstream.avail_in = nByte;
        ^^^^^^^^^
        So you only assign to zstream.avail_in when nByte > 0

    ....
    ....

    if (zstream.avail_in == 0) break;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        Consequently this will not be true when nByte is zero and the
        code will not exit
```

Try this instead:

```
    zstream.avail_in = nByte;  // Unconditional assignment

    ....

    if (zstream.avail_in <= 0) break;  // Less or equal to zero
```

Comment: No, it did not solve the problem. I checked the two versions side by side. All variable values and number of cycles are the same. I think the problem is stream or something.. Interestingly when I create the file in the function, same problem continues. This is crazy.

Comment: Well - your logic in the second example is wrong but maybe you break out of the outer loop due to the return value from `inflate`. I don't know if it matters but I noticed that your first example calls `inflateEnd` but your second example does not.

Comment: You're right about second example, thank you. I solved the problem. The problem stems from the failure to turn off the file stream. I'm using the C-style file system. When file closed properly problem solved. When exited function and called destructor, the file writes incomplete.(512 bytes)